# iframe not taking full height of cell in firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe, height, cell

http://onlinehandytools.com/blah.php?board=EDE&level=AL&subject=biology&year=2011

If you click on any of the links labeled QP/MS in Firefox/Opera the iframe won't take up the full height and only takes up about 10% of the height. Not sure why this is happening as it's working perfectly fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only given the `table` those iframes are sitting in `height:100%` – but that doesn’t mean the elements inside the table have to take that height as well.

Give the `tbody`, `tr` and `td` elements inside that table the same height as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the `<doctype>` you used, since iFrame are not supported with XHTML strict Doctype 1.0

In general the use of iFrames is not a good practice, it would be better to use other methods like dhtml and ajax; however there are cases (like your one) when an iFrame is necessary.

So, here there are some solutions:

1. Use a less-restrictive DTD, like transitional:
   `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`, which allows the use of iFrames
2. Use a "tricky" custom DTD, like explained in this article: http://madskristensen.net/post/use-iframes-with-xhtml-10-strict, which simply expands the standard Strict DTD with the iFrame definitions from the Transitional DTD
3. Convert the iFrame into an Object, like explained here: http://sumitbansal.com/web-designing-tips/w3c-validation-iframe-error-with-xhtml-1-0-strict-doctype/
4. Calculate the height of the TD using javascript, and assign it to the iFrame; something like `document.getElementById('the-iframe-id').style.height = document.getElementById('the-td-id').offsetHeight + 'px';`

I hope this may help.

Comment: I've tried 1,3 and 4 they didn't work
4: gave me a height of 0 when I got the offsetHeight, I tried the .height method from jquery it didn't work also
 ... 
3: I converted it to an object it worked on chrome but same result on firefox

Comment: nvm I did this '      $("#iframing").css("height",$("body").height()+"px");' It worked fine. even when I'm resizing it, that's weird.Thanks anyway :D

Comment: oh it only works if the height of the body is the full height of the window

Comment: I took a look at your code: in the moment you create the TD, the div which contains it is display:none so, actually, the height of the TD is zero. Then you call a show() function and the TD gets a style.display='block' property and, accordingly, its height. So if you want to use method #4 with the TD height, please try to put the code after that style.display='block' code

Comment: nice, you are smart.
I did that but it's still not getting the full height.
it has something to do when I fullscreen the window, because when I cancel the fullscreen the height is good